# Weird pip bug. Can't install some modules but I can install others

Tags: python, pip, grequests

Despite my best effors, I can't seem to get gevent or grequests working. They both rely on greenlet which I can't get working either.

I've completely installed and reinstalled python via homebrew. I haven't tried using python's installer but I don't see why that would matter. I have upgraded xcode to the latest version and installed literally every plugin. I regularly have success installing python modules via pip. I've been trying to install grequests for the last month.

Computer:

- Mac OSX Yosemite Version 10.10.1
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
- 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

`

```
$ sudo pip install greenlet
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

$ sudo pip install gevent
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gevent in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent)
Cleaning up...

$ sudo pip install grequests
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): grequests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gevent in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from grequests)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=1.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from grequests)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): greenlet in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gevent->grequests)
Cleaning up...
```

'

```
>>> import grequests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import grequests
ImportError: No module named grequests

>>> import greenlet    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import greenlet
ImportError: No module named greenlet

>>> import gevent    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import gevent
ImportError: No module named gevent
```

Edit:

```
$ which -a python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Edit 2:

I must have broken something at some point because now none of the modules I install are coming through. The modules I've installed in the past still work but the new ones are getting the same errors as above.

Comment: Can you add the output of `which -a python` to your question?

Comment: looks like the interpreters in your path are not in the right order. Does `/usr/local/bin/python -c 'import grequests'` print an error message?

Comment: It seems that pip install has stopped working all together. This is very frustrating. I may end up reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Reinstalling your OS is probably not necessary. Yet removing all python distributions and `site-packages` directories except OSX native python version and reinstalling afterwards might solve this problem.
I can recommend switching to the `anaconda` or `miniconda` scientific python distributions. It may take some time to get used to the concept of virtualenvs, but believe me, it will make life easier in the long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reinstalling everything, I still had the problem. I thought that `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` was the system installed version, but it's not.

I needed to delete that and remove it from `~/.bash_profile` that and then everything worked fine. I don't know if that was my only problem as the reinstall could have fixed something, but I think it was.